# Filtering array with RXJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I am trying filtering the return of HTTP request in Angular 7 using RXJS6.

I must filter the response; only get the Users with IdSkill equals to 1234.

However, I cannot achieve this. I just received this error:

*Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable>'.
  Type 'User[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Pagination': total, items*

RXJS is not my strong skill; I just use the basics, only to do simple get/post HTTP requests.

My code:

```
/* Interface */
export interface Pagination<t> {
    total: number;
    items: t[];
}

export interface User {
    idUser: number;
    name: string;
    active: boolean;
    skill: Skill;
}

export interface Skill {
    idSkill: number;
    name: string;
}

/* Service */
getUsers(): Observable<Pagination<User>> {
    return this._httpClient.get<Pagination<User>>(
      'http://localhost/api/users',
      { headers: this._auth }
    ).pipe(
      filter(x => x.items.filter(user => user.skill.idSkill == 1234))
    );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The operator you need would be a `map`, since you want to remap (filter) your inner result. RxJs `filter` is used when you want to filter the result itself that was emitted from Observable.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


/* Service */
getUsers(): Observable<Pagination<User>> {
    return this._httpClient.get<Pagination<User>>(
      'http://localhost/api/users',
      { headers: this._auth }
    ).pipe(
      map((pagination: Pagination<User>) => ({
         ...pagination,
         items: pagination.items.filter(user => user.skill.idSkill == 1234)
      }))
    );
}
```

Comment: Hmm... while this is true and needed for correct functionality, this may not be the entire picture as `x.items.filter` returns a truthy value and allows the code to work. The type error seems be elsewhere

Comment: That looks like JavaScript's `filter` not RxJS's. But `Map` looks helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint returns what is returns so simply use `find` to get the single match out of it. Or `filter` to give you an array of matches.

```
getUsers(): Observable<Pagination<User>> {
    return this._httpClient.get<Pagination<User>>(url,{ headers: this._auth })
       .pipe(take(1))
       .subscribe(users => {

            // finds a single result
            theObject = users.find(obj => obj.IdSkill == 5);

            // return an array of all matching results
            arrayOfResults = data.filter(obj => obj.IdSkill === 'JavaSc');

       });
}
```